# How can I access nested data in Firebase with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am working on building a simple app with React and Firebase - a way to manage income and expenditure, and my Firebase is set up with the following structure:

```
"cashbook" : {
  "expenditure" : {
    "expenditure-1" : {
      "amount" : "500",
      "category" : "insurance",
      "date" : "date",
      "name" : "Life Insurance",
      "type" : "recurring"
    }
  },
  "income" : {
    "salary" : {
      "amount" : "500",
      "category" : "salary",
      "date" : "date",
      "type" : "recurring"
    }
  }
}
```

I have React set up and working perfectly with just the expenditure, using [Re-base](https://www.npmjs.com/package/re-base):

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    // Two way data binding
    base.syncState('cashbook/expenditure', {
      context: this,
      state: 'expenditure'
    });
  },
```

I can then reference using: `this.state.expenditure`

However, when I try to expand the app to access the Income data, things go pear shaped. I amended the componentdidmount to:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    // Two way data binding
    base.syncState('cashbook', {
      context: this,
      state: 'cashbook'
    });
  },
```

And try to access with `this.state.cashbook.expenditure` and `this.state.cashbook.income`, but no joy, I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'expenditure' of undefined`.

Not quite sure what to try, any pointers would be divine brown.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What happens when you try to access those things? Do you get a specific error message? If you look at the component's state with the React developer tools, what do you see?

Comment: Apologies. Updated main post, but the error is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'expenditure' of undefined`

Comment: Creator of Re-base here. This sounds like it may be an issue with Re-base since your code looks fine. Would you mind creating an issue on the project and I'll take a look at it?

Comment: Hi Tyler, apologies, Christmas got in the way! It wasn't an issue with Re-base, I just needed to use syncstate on `cashbook` instead of `cashbook/expenditure` and call `this.state.cashbook.expenditure`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was being a moron :)

I just needed to use syncstate on `cashbook` instead of `cashbook/expenditure` and call `this.state.cashbook.expenditure`.